Zephyr Mqtt_publisher: error while trying to connect to a TLS MQTT broker
I have take the mqtt_publisher sample in the zephyr-project repo and I added a wi-fi connection ot it.
I'm using a esp32_devkitc_wroom.
Here is the main.c:
#include <zephyr/logging/log.h>
LOG_MODULE_REGISTER(net_mqtt_publisher_sample, LOG_LEVEL_DBG);

#include <zephyr/kernel.h>
#include <zephyr/net/net_if.h>
#include <zephyr/net/wifi_mgmt.h>
#include <zephyr/net/net_event.h>
#include <zephyr/net/socket.h>
#include <zephyr/net/mqtt.h>
#include <zephyr/random/random.h>
#include <zephyr/linker/sections.h>
#include <zephyr/net/net_core.h>
#include <zephyr/net/net_mgmt.h>
#include <zephyr/net/dns_resolve.h>
#include <zephyr/data/json.h>
#include <zephyr/net/net_context.h>

#include <zephyr/sys/printk.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

#include "config.h"
#include "net_sample_common.h"
#include "wifi_cred.h"

#if defined(CONFIG_USERSPACE)
#include <zephyr/app_memory/app_memdomain.h>
K_APPMEM_PARTITION_DEFINE(app_partition);
struct k_mem_domain app_domain;
#define APP_BMEM K_APP_BMEM(app_partition)
#define APP_DMEM K_APP_DMEM(app_partition)
#else
#define APP_BMEM
#define APP_DMEM
#endif

#define SOCKS5_PROXY_PORT 1080  // Replace with your actual SOCKS5 proxy port
#define SOCKS5_PROXY_ADDR "192.168.1.1"

static K_SEM_DEFINE(wifi_connected, 0, 1);              // added
static K_SEM_DEFINE(ipv4_address_obtained, 0, 1);       // added

static struct net_mgmt_event_callback wifi_cb;          // added
static struct net_mgmt_event_callback ipv4_cb;          // added

/* Buffers for MQTT client. */
static APP_BMEM uint8_t rx_buffer[APP_MQTT_BUFFER_SIZE];
static APP_BMEM uint8_t tx_buffer[APP_MQTT_BUFFER_SIZE];

#if defined(CONFIG_MQTT_LIB_WEBSOCKET)
/* Making RX buffer large enough that the full IPv6 packet can fit into it */
#define MQTT_LIB_WEBSOCKET_RECV_BUF_LEN 1280

/* Websocket needs temporary buffer to store partial packets */
static APP_BMEM uint8_t temp_ws_rx_buf[MQTT_LIB_WEBSOCKET_RECV_BUF_LEN];
#endif

/* The mqtt client struct */
static APP_BMEM struct mqtt_client client_ctx;

/* MQTT Broker details. */
static APP_BMEM struct sockaddr_storage broker;

#if defined(CONFIG_SOCKS)
static APP_BMEM struct sockaddr socks5_proxy;
#endif

static APP_BMEM struct pollfd fds[1];
static APP_BMEM int nfds;

static APP_BMEM bool connected;

#if defined(CONFIG_MQTT_LIB_TLS)

#define SERVER_PORT SERVER_PORT_TLS
#include "cert.h"

#define TLS_SNI_HOSTNAME "test.mosquitto.org"
#define APP_CA_CERT_TAG 1
#define APP_PSK_TAG 2

static APP_DMEM sec_tag_t m_sec_tags[] = {
#if defined(MBEDTLS_X509_CRT_PARSE_C) || defined(CONFIG_NET_SOCKETS_OFFLOAD)
        APP_CA_CERT_TAG,
#endif
#if defined(MBEDTLS_KEY_EXCHANGE_SOME_PSK_ENABLED)
        APP_PSK_TAG,
#endif
};

static int tls_init(void)
{
    int err = -EINVAL;

#if defined(MBEDTLS_X509_CRT_PARSE_C) || defined(CONFIG_NET_SOCKETS_OFFLOAD)
    err = tls_credential_add(APP_CA_CERT_TAG, TLS_CREDENTIAL_CA_CERTIFICATE,
                 ca_certificate, sizeof(ca_certificate));

    if (err < 0) {
        LOG_ERR("Failed to register public certificate: %d", err);
            printk("sono qui\n");
        return err;
    }
#endif

#if defined(MBEDTLS_KEY_EXCHANGE_SOME_PSK_ENABLED)
    err = tls_credential_add(APP_PSK_TAG, TLS_CREDENTIAL_PSK,
                 client_psk, sizeof(client_psk));
    if (err < 0) {
        LOG_ERR("Failed to register PSK: %d", err);
        return err;
    }

    err = tls_credential_add(APP_PSK_TAG, TLS_CREDENTIAL_PSK_ID,
                 client_psk_id, sizeof(client_psk_id) - 1);
    if (err < 0) {
        LOG_ERR("Failed to register PSK ID: %d", err);
    }
#endif

    return err;
}

#endif /* CONFIG_MQTT_LIB_TLS */

static void prepare_fds(struct mqtt_client *client)
{
    if (client->transport.type == MQTT_TRANSPORT_NON_SECURE) {
        fds[0].fd = client->transport.tcp.sock;
    }
#if defined(CONFIG_MQTT_LIB_TLS)
    else if (client->transport.type == MQTT_TRANSPORT_SECURE) {
        fds[0].fd = client->transport.tls.sock;
    }
#endif

    fds[0].events = POLLIN;
    nfds = 1;
}

static void clear_fds(void)
{
    nfds = 0;
}

static int wait(int timeout)
{
    int ret = 0;

    if (nfds > 0) {
        ret = poll(fds, nfds, timeout);
        if (ret < 0) {
            LOG_ERR("poll error: %d", errno);
        }
    }

    return ret;
}

// added code for mqtt subscriber

static void on_mqtt_publish(struct mqtt_client *const client, const struct mqtt_evt *evt)
{
    int rc;
    uint8_t payload[APP_MQTT_BUFFER_SIZE];

    rc = mqtt_read_publish_payload(client, payload,
                    APP_MQTT_BUFFER_SIZE);
    if (rc < 0) {
        LOG_ERR("Failed to read received MQTT payload [%d]", rc);
        return;
    }
    /* Place null terminator at end of payload buffer */
    payload[rc] = '\0';
    
    printk("MQTT payload received!\n");
    LOG_INF("MQTT payload received!");
    printk("topic: '%s', payload: %s\n",
        evt->param.publish.message.topic.topic.utf8, payload);

    // /* If the topic is a command, call the command handler  */
    // if (strcmp(evt->param.publish.message.topic.topic.utf8,
    //      MQTT_TOPIC) == 0) {
    //  device_command_handler(payload);
    // }
}

int app_mqtt_subscribe(struct mqtt_client *client)
{
    int rc;
    struct mqtt_topic sub_topics[] = {
        {
            .topic = {
                .utf8 = MQTT_TOPIC,
                .size = strlen(sub_topics->topic.utf8)
            },
            .qos = IS_ENABLED(CONFIG_NET_SAMPLE_MQTT_QOS_0_AT_MOST_ONCE) ? 0 :
                (IS_ENABLED(CONFIG_NET_SAMPLE_MQTT_QOS_1_AT_LEAST_ONCE) ? 1 : 2)
        }
    };
    const struct mqtt_subscription_list sub_list = {
        .list = sub_topics,
        .list_count = ARRAY_SIZE(sub_topics),
        .message_id = 5841u
    };

    LOG_INF("Subscribing to %d topic(s)", sub_list.list_count);

    rc = mqtt_subscribe(client, &sub_list);
    if (rc != 0) {
        LOG_ERR("MQTT Subscribe failed [%d]", rc);
    }
    else
    {
        LOG_INF("MQTT Subscribe success [%d]", rc);
    }

    return rc;
}

// end code for mqtt subscriber

void mqtt_evt_handler(struct mqtt_client *const client,
              const struct mqtt_evt *evt)
{
    int err;

    switch (evt->type) {
    case MQTT_EVT_CONNACK:
        if (evt->result != 0) {
            LOG_ERR("MQTT connect failed %d", evt->result);
            break;
        }

        connected = true;
        LOG_INF("MQTT client connected!");

        app_mqtt_subscribe(client);

        break;

    case MQTT_EVT_DISCONNECT:
        LOG_INF("MQTT client disconnected %d", evt->result);

        connected = false;
        clear_fds();

        break;

    case MQTT_EVT_PUBACK:
        if (evt->result != 0) {
            LOG_ERR("MQTT PUBACK error %d", evt->result);
            break;
        }

        LOG_INF("PUBACK packet id: %u", evt->param.puback.message_id);

        break;

    case MQTT_EVT_SUBACK:  // Add this case to handle subscription acknowledgment
        if (evt->result != 0) {
            LOG_ERR("MQTT SUBACK error %d", evt->result);
            break;
        }
        LOG_INF("Subscription acknowledged, id: %u", evt->param.suback.message_id);

    break;
        
    case MQTT_EVT_PUBREC:
        if (evt->result != 0) {
            LOG_ERR("MQTT PUBREC error %d", evt->result);
            break;
        }

        LOG_INF("PUBREC packet id: %u", evt->param.pubrec.message_id);

        const struct mqtt_pubrel_param rel_param = {
            .message_id = evt->param.pubrec.message_id
        };

        err = mqtt_publish_qos2_release(client, &rel_param);
        if (err != 0) {
            LOG_ERR("Failed to send MQTT PUBREL: %d", err);
        }

        break;

    case MQTT_EVT_PUBREL:                                       // non presente in mqtt_publisher
        if (evt->result != 0) {                                 // serve per QoS2
            LOG_ERR("MQTT PUBREL error [%d]", evt->result);
            break;
        }

        LOG_INF("PUBREL packet ID: %u", evt->param.pubrel.message_id);

        const struct mqtt_pubcomp_param rec_param = {
            .message_id = evt->param.pubrel.message_id
        };

        mqtt_publish_qos2_complete(client, &rec_param);
        break;

    case MQTT_EVT_PUBCOMP:
        if (evt->result != 0) {
            LOG_ERR("MQTT PUBCOMP error %d", evt->result);
            break;
        }

        LOG_INF("PUBCOMP packet id: %u",
            evt->param.pubcomp.message_id);

        break;

    case MQTT_EVT_PINGRESP:
        LOG_INF("PINGRESP packet");
        break;

    case MQTT_EVT_PUBLISH:                                              // non presente in mqtt_publisher
        const struct mqtt_publish_param *p = &evt->param.publish;       // serve per pubblicare messaggi su un topic a cui il client è sottoscritto

        if (p->message.topic.qos == MQTT_QOS_1_AT_LEAST_ONCE) {
            const struct mqtt_puback_param ack_param = {
                .message_id = p->message_id
            };
            mqtt_publish_qos1_ack(client, &ack_param);
        } else if (p->message.topic.qos == MQTT_QOS_2_EXACTLY_ONCE) {
            const struct mqtt_pubrec_param rec_param = {
                .message_id = p->message_id
            };
            mqtt_publish_qos2_receive(client, &rec_param);
        }

        on_mqtt_publish(client, evt);

    default:
        break;
    }
}

static char *get_mqtt_payload(enum mqtt_qos qos)
{
#if APP_BLUEMIX_TOPIC
    static APP_BMEM char payload[30];

    snprintk(payload, sizeof(payload), "{d:{temperature:%d}}",
         sys_rand8_get());
#else
    static APP_DMEM char payload[] = "DOORS:OPEN_QoSx";

    payload[strlen(payload) - 1] = '0' + qos;
#endif

    return payload;
}

static char *get_mqtt_topic(void)
{
#if APP_BLUEMIX_TOPIC
    return "iot-2/type/"BLUEMIX_DEVTYPE"/id/"BLUEMIX_DEVID
           "/evt/"BLUEMIX_EVENT"/fmt/"BLUEMIX_FORMAT;
#else
    return "testtopic/federzep";
#endif
}

static int publish(struct mqtt_client *client, enum mqtt_qos qos)
{
    struct mqtt_publish_param param;

    param.message.topic.qos = qos;
    param.message.topic.topic.utf8 = (uint8_t *)get_mqtt_topic();
    param.message.topic.topic.size =
            strlen(param.message.topic.topic.utf8);
    param.message.payload.data = get_mqtt_payload(qos);
    param.message.payload.len =
            strlen(param.message.payload.data);
    param.message_id = sys_rand16_get();
    param.dup_flag = 0U;
    param.retain_flag = 0U;

    return mqtt_publish(client, &param);
}

#define RC_STR(rc) ((rc) == 0 ? "OK" : "ERROR")

#define PRINT_RESULT(func, rc) \
    LOG_INF("%s: %d <%s>", (func), rc, RC_STR(rc));

static void broker_init(void)
{
#if defined(CONFIG_NET_IPV6)
    struct sockaddr_in6 *broker6 = (struct sockaddr_in6 *)&broker;

    broker6->sin6_family = AF_INET6;
    broker6->sin6_port = htons(SERVER_PORT);
    inet_pton(AF_INET6, SERVER_ADDR, &broker6->sin6_addr);

#if defined(CONFIG_SOCKS)
    struct sockaddr_in6 *proxy6 = (struct sockaddr_in6 *)&socks5_proxy;

    proxy6->sin6_family = AF_INET6;
    proxy6->sin6_port = htons(SOCKS5_PROXY_PORT);
    inet_pton(AF_INET6, SOCKS5_PROXY_ADDR, &proxy6->sin6_addr);
#endif
#else
    struct sockaddr_in *broker4 = (struct sockaddr_in *)&broker;

    broker4->sin_family = AF_INET;
    broker4->sin_port = htons(SERVER_PORT);
    inet_pton(AF_INET, SERVER_ADDR, &broker4->sin_addr);
#if defined(CONFIG_SOCKS)
    struct sockaddr_in *proxy4 = (struct sockaddr_in *)&socks5_proxy;
    #define SOCKS5_PROXY_PORT 1080  // Replace with your actual SOCKS5 proxy port
    proxy4->sin_family = AF_INET;
    proxy4->sin_port = htons(SOCKS5_PROXY_PORT);
    inet_pton(AF_INET, SOCKS5_PROXY_ADDR, &proxy4->sin_addr);
#endif
#endif
}

static void client_init(struct mqtt_client *client)
{
    mqtt_client_init(client);
    // printk("mqtt_client_init test\n");
    broker_init();
    // printk("broker_init test\n");
    /* MQTT client configuration */
    client->broker = &broker;
    client->evt_cb = mqtt_evt_handler;
    client->client_id.utf8 = (uint8_t *)MQTT_CLIENTID;
    client->client_id.size = strlen(MQTT_CLIENTID);
    client->password = MQTT_PASS /*NULL*/;
    client->user_name = MQTT_USER /*NULL*/;
    client->protocol_version = MQTT_VERSION_3_1_1;

    /* MQTT buffers configuration */
    client->rx_buf = rx_buffer;
    client->rx_buf_size = sizeof(rx_buffer);
    client->tx_buf = tx_buffer;
    client->tx_buf_size = sizeof(tx_buffer);

    /* MQTT transport configuration */
#if defined(CONFIG_MQTT_LIB_TLS)
#if defined(CONFIG_MQTT_LIB_WEBSOCKET)
    client->transport.type = MQTT_TRANSPORT_SECURE_WEBSOCKET;
#else
    client->transport.type = MQTT_TRANSPORT_SECURE;
#endif

    struct mqtt_sec_config *tls_config = &client->transport.tls.config;

    tls_config->peer_verify = TLS_PEER_VERIFY_REQUIRED;
    tls_config->cipher_list = NULL;
    tls_config->sec_tag_list = m_sec_tags;
    tls_config->sec_tag_count = ARRAY_SIZE(m_sec_tags);
#if defined(MBEDTLS_X509_CRT_PARSE_C) || defined(CONFIG_NET_SOCKETS_OFFLOAD)
    tls_config->hostname = TLS_SNI_HOSTNAME;
#else
    tls_config->hostname = NULL;
#endif

#else
#if defined(CONFIG_MQTT_LIB_WEBSOCKET)
    client->transport.type = MQTT_TRANSPORT_NON_SECURE_WEBSOCKET;
#else
    client->transport.type = MQTT_TRANSPORT_NON_SECURE;
#endif
#endif

#if defined(CONFIG_MQTT_LIB_WEBSOCKET)
    client->transport.websocket.config.host = SERVER_ADDR;
    client->transport.websocket.config.url = "/mqtt";
    client->transport.websocket.config.tmp_buf = temp_ws_rx_buf;
    client->transport.websocket.config.tmp_buf_len =
                        sizeof(temp_ws_rx_buf);
    client->transport.websocket.timeout = 50 * MSEC_PER_SEC;
#endif

#if defined(CONFIG_SOCKS)
    mqtt_client_set_proxy(client, &socks5_proxy,
                  socks5_proxy.sa_family == AF_INET ?
                  sizeof(struct sockaddr_in) :
                  sizeof(struct sockaddr_in6));
#endif
}

/* Subscribe to a topic */
// static void subscribe_topic(struct mqtt_client *client)
// {
//     struct mqtt_topic topic = {
//         .topic = {
//             .utf8 = (uint8_t *)"testtopic/federzep",
//             .size = strlen("testtopic/federzep")
//         },
//         .qos = MQTT_QOS_1_AT_LEAST_ONCE,
//     };

//     struct mqtt_subscription_list subs = {
//         .list = &topic,
//         .list_count = 1,
//         .message_id = sys_rand32_get(),
//     };

//     int ret = mqtt_subscribe(client, &subs);
//     if (ret) {
//         LOG_ERR("Failed to subscribe to topic (err %d)", ret);
//     } else {
//         LOG_INF("Subscription request sent");
//     }
// }

/* In this routine we block until the connected variable is 1 */
static int try_to_connect(struct mqtt_client *client)
{
    int rc, i = 0;
    // printk("0t\n");
    while (i++ < APP_CONNECT_TRIES && !connected) {

        client_init(client);
        // printk("client_init test\n");
        rc = mqtt_connect(client);
        // printk("mqtt_connect test\n");
        if (rc != 0) {
            PRINT_RESULT("mqtt_connect", rc);
            k_sleep(K_MSEC(APP_SLEEP_MSECS));
            continue;
        }

        prepare_fds(client);

        if (wait(APP_CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MS)) {
            mqtt_input(client);
        }

        if (!connected) {
            mqtt_abort(client);
            printk("Disconnected from mqtt");
        }
    }

    if (connected) {
        return 0;
    }

    return -EINVAL;
}

static int process_mqtt_and_sleep(struct mqtt_client *client, int timeout)
{
    int64_t remaining = timeout;
    int64_t start_time = k_uptime_get();
    int rc;
    // printk(" valore connected %d \n",connected);
    while (remaining > 0 && connected) {
        if (wait(remaining)) {
            rc = mqtt_input(client);
            if (rc != 0) {
                PRINT_RESULT("mqtt_input", rc);
                return rc;
            }
        }

        rc = mqtt_live(client);
        if (rc != 0 && rc != -EAGAIN) {
            PRINT_RESULT("mqtt_live", rc);
            return rc;
        } else if (rc == 0) {
            rc = mqtt_input(client);
            if (rc != 0) {
                PRINT_RESULT("mqtt_input", rc);
                return rc;
            }
        }

        remaining = timeout + start_time - k_uptime_get();
    }

    return 0;
}

#define SUCCESS_OR_EXIT(rc) { if (rc != 0) { return 1; } }
#define SUCCESS_OR_BREAK(rc) { if (rc != 0) { break; } }

static int publisher(void)
{
    int i, rc, r = 0;
    // printk("0p\n");
    LOG_INF("attempting to connect: ");
    rc = try_to_connect(&client_ctx);
    PRINT_RESULT("try_to_connect", rc);
    SUCCESS_OR_EXIT(rc);
    // printk("i'm out of while\n");
    i = 0;
    k_msleep(5000);
    while (i++ < CONFIG_NET_SAMPLE_APP_MAX_ITERATIONS && connected) {
        r = -1;

        rc = mqtt_ping(&client_ctx);
        PRINT_RESULT("mqtt_ping", rc);
        SUCCESS_OR_BREAK(rc);
        // printk("i'm here in the while");
        rc = process_mqtt_and_sleep(&client_ctx, APP_CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MS);
        SUCCESS_OR_BREAK(rc);

        rc = publish(&client_ctx, MQTT_QOS_0_AT_MOST_ONCE);
        PRINT_RESULT("mqtt_publish", rc);
        SUCCESS_OR_BREAK(rc);

        rc = process_mqtt_and_sleep(&client_ctx, APP_CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MS);
        SUCCESS_OR_BREAK(rc);

        rc = publish(&client_ctx, MQTT_QOS_1_AT_LEAST_ONCE);
        PRINT_RESULT("mqtt_publish", rc);
        SUCCESS_OR_BREAK(rc);

        rc = process_mqtt_and_sleep(&client_ctx, APP_CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MS);
        SUCCESS_OR_BREAK(rc);

        rc = publish(&client_ctx, MQTT_QOS_2_EXACTLY_ONCE);
        PRINT_RESULT("mqtt_publish", rc);
        SUCCESS_OR_BREAK(rc);

        rc = process_mqtt_and_sleep(&client_ctx, APP_CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MS);
        SUCCESS_OR_BREAK(rc);

        r = 0;
    }

    rc = mqtt_disconnect(&client_ctx);
    PRINT_RESULT("mqtt_disconnect", rc);

    LOG_INF("Bye!");

    return r;
}

static int start_app(void)
{
    int r = 0, i = 0;
    
    // printk("0s\n");

    while (!CONFIG_NET_SAMPLE_APP_MAX_CONNECTIONS ||
           i++ < CONFIG_NET_SAMPLE_APP_MAX_CONNECTIONS) {
        r = publisher();

        if (!CONFIG_NET_SAMPLE_APP_MAX_CONNECTIONS) {
            k_sleep(K_MSEC(5000));
        }
    }
    // printk("0s\n");
    return r;
}

#if defined(CONFIG_USERSPACE)
#define STACK_SIZE 2048

#if defined(CONFIG_NET_TC_THREAD_COOPERATIVE)
#define THREAD_PRIORITY K_PRIO_COOP(CONFIG_NUM_COOP_PRIORITIES - 1)
#else
#define THREAD_PRIORITY K_PRIO_PREEMPT(8)
#endif

K_THREAD_DEFINE(app_thread, STACK_SIZE,
        start_app, NULL, NULL, NULL,
        THREAD_PRIORITY, K_USER, -1);

static K_HEAP_DEFINE(app_mem_pool, 1024 * 2);
#endif

// added code for wifi connection

static void handle_wifi_connect_result(struct net_mgmt_event_callback *cb)
{
    const struct wifi_status *status = (const struct wifi_status *)cb->info;

    if (status->status)
    {
        printk("Connection request failed (%d)\n", status->status);
    }
    else
    {
        printk("Connected (%lld)\n", k_uptime_get());
        k_sem_give(&wifi_connected);
    }
}

static void handle_wifi_disconnect_result(struct net_mgmt_event_callback *cb)
{
    const struct wifi_status *status = (const struct wifi_status *)cb->info;

    if (status->status)
    {
        printk("Disconnection request (%d)\n", status->status);
    }
    else
    {
        printk("Disconnected (%lld)\n", k_uptime_get());
        k_sem_take(&wifi_connected, K_NO_WAIT);
    }
}

static void handle_ipv4_result(struct net_if *iface)
{
    int i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < NET_IF_MAX_IPV4_ADDR; i++) {

        char buf[NET_IPV4_ADDR_LEN];

        printk("IPv4 address: %s\n",
                net_addr_ntop(AF_INET,
                                &iface->config.ip.ipv4->unicast[i].ipv4,
                                buf, sizeof(buf)));
        printk("Subnet: %s\n",
                net_addr_ntop(AF_INET,
                                &iface->config.ip.ipv4->unicast[i].netmask,
                                buf, sizeof(buf)));
        printk("Router: %s\n",
                net_addr_ntop(AF_INET,
                                &iface->config.ip.ipv4->gw,
                                buf, sizeof(buf)));
        }

        k_sem_give(&ipv4_address_obtained);
}

static void wifi_mgmt_event_handler(struct net_mgmt_event_callback *cb, uint32_t mgmt_event, struct net_if *iface)
{
    switch (mgmt_event)
    {

        case NET_EVENT_WIFI_CONNECT_RESULT:
            handle_wifi_connect_result(cb);
            break;

        case NET_EVENT_WIFI_DISCONNECT_RESULT:
            handle_wifi_disconnect_result(cb);
            break;

        case NET_EVENT_IPV4_ADDR_ADD:
            handle_ipv4_result(iface);
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}

void wifi_connect(void)
{
    struct net_if *iface = net_if_get_default();

    struct wifi_connect_req_params wifi_params = {0};

    wifi_params.ssid = SSID;
    wifi_params.psk = PSK;
    wifi_params.ssid_length = strlen(SSID);
    wifi_params.psk_length = strlen(PSK);
    wifi_params.channel = WIFI_CHANNEL_ANY;
    wifi_params.security = WIFI_SECURITY_TYPE_PSK;
    wifi_params.band = WIFI_FREQ_BAND_2_4_GHZ; 
    wifi_params.mfp = WIFI_MFP_OPTIONAL;

    printk("Connecting to SSID: %s\n", wifi_params.ssid);

    if (net_mgmt(NET_REQUEST_WIFI_CONNECT, iface, &wifi_params, sizeof(struct wifi_connect_req_params)))
    {
        printk("WiFi Connection Request Failed\n");
    }
}

void wifi_status(void)
{
    struct net_if *iface = net_if_get_default();
    
    struct wifi_iface_status status = {0};

    if (net_mgmt(NET_REQUEST_WIFI_IFACE_STATUS, iface, &status, sizeof(struct wifi_iface_status)))
    {
        printk("WiFi Status Request Failed\n");
    }

    printk("\n");

    if (status.state >= WIFI_STATE_ASSOCIATED) {
        printk("SSID: %-32s\n", status.ssid);
        printk("Band: %s\n", wifi_band_txt(status.band));
        printk("Channel: %d\n", status.channel);
        printk("Security: %s\n", wifi_security_txt(status.security));
        printk("RSSI: %d\n", status.rssi);
    }
}

void wifi_disconnect(void)
{
    struct net_if *iface = net_if_get_default();

    if (net_mgmt(NET_REQUEST_WIFI_DISCONNECT, iface, NULL, 0))
    {
        printk("WiFi Disconnection Request Failed\n");
    }
}

// end code for wifi connection

int main(void)
{
    printk("WiFi Example\nBoard: %s\n", CONFIG_BOARD);

    net_mgmt_init_event_callback(&wifi_cb, wifi_mgmt_event_handler,
                                 NET_EVENT_WIFI_CONNECT_RESULT | NET_EVENT_WIFI_DISCONNECT_RESULT);

    net_mgmt_init_event_callback(&ipv4_cb, wifi_mgmt_event_handler, NET_EVENT_IPV4_ADDR_ADD);

    net_mgmt_add_event_callback(&wifi_cb);
    net_mgmt_add_event_callback(&ipv4_cb);

    wifi_connect();
    k_sem_take(&wifi_connected, K_FOREVER);
    wifi_status();
    k_sem_take(&ipv4_address_obtained, K_FOREVER);
    printk("Ready...\n\n");


#if defined(CONFIG_MQTT_LIB_TLS)
    int rc;
    // printk("0x\n");
    rc = tls_init();
    PRINT_RESULT("tls_init", rc);
#endif

#if defined(CONFIG_USERSPACE)

    int ret;
    // printk("0x\n");
    struct k_mem_partition *parts[] = {
#if Z_LIBC_PARTITION_EXISTS
        &z_libc_partition,
#endif
        &app_partition
    };

    ret = k_mem_domain_init(&app_domain, ARRAY_SIZE(parts), parts);
    __ASSERT(ret == 0, "k_mem_domain_init() failed %d", ret);
    ARG_UNUSED(ret);
    // printk("0y\n");
    k_mem_domain_add_thread(&app_domain, app_thread);
    k_thread_heap_assign(app_thread, &app_mem_pool);

    // printk("0y\n");

    k_thread_start(app_thread);
    k_thread_join(app_thread, K_FOREVER);
#else
    exit(start_app());
#endif
    return 0;
}


While this is the prj.conf:
CONFIG_WIFI=y
CONFIG_INIT_STACKS=y
CONFIG_NET_L2_WIFI_MGMT=y

CONFIG_NETWORKING=y     
CONFIG_NET_SOCKETS=y       
CONFIG_NET_TCP=y        
CONFIG_NET_LOG=y
CONFIG_NET_SOCKETS_OFFLOAD=y
CONFIG_MDNS_RESOLVER=y

# CONFIG_NET_IPV6_RA_RDNSS=y
# CONFIG_NET_IF_UNICAST_IPV6_ADDR_COUNT=3
# CONFIG_NET_IF_MCAST_IPV6_ADDR_COUNT=2

CONFIG_ESP32_WIFI_STA_AUTO_DHCPV4=y
CONFIG_ESP32_WIFI_STA_RECONNECT=y

CONFIG_PRINTK=y         
CONFIG_STDOUT_CONSOLE=y 
CONFIG_POSIX_API=y      

# Enable IPv6 support
CONFIG_NET_IPV6=n       
# Enable IPv4 support
CONFIG_NET_IPV4=y       

CONFIG_NET_UDP=y
CONFIG_DNS_RESOLVER=n
CONFIG_DNS_RESOLVER_AI_MAX_ENTRIES=10

CONFIG_HTTP_CLIENT=y

# Use DHCP for IPv4
CONFIG_NET_DHCPV4=y

# Enable the MQTT Lib
CONFIG_MQTT_LIB=y    
CONFIG_MQTT_LIB_TLS=y

CONFIG_NET_CONFIG_SETTINGS=y                            
# CONFIG_NET_CONFIG_MY_IPV6_ADDR="2001:db8::1"
# CONFIG_NET_CONFIG_PEER_IPV6_ADDR="2001:db8::2"

# CONFIG_NET_CONFIG_MY_IPV4_ADDR="192.168.218.28"
# CONFIG_NET_CONFIG_PEER_IPV4_ADDR="192.168.218.200"

CONFIG_MAIN_STACK_SIZE=2048                             

CONFIG_NET_CONFIG_INIT_TIMEOUT=1

CONFIG_TLS_CREDENTIALS=y

CONFIG_NET_SOCKETS_SOCKOPT_TLS=y

# Enable Mbed TLS       error when enabled
CONFIG_MBEDTLS=y
CONFIG_MBEDTLS_BUILTIN=y
CONFIG_MBEDTLS_ENABLE_HEAP=y
CONFIG_MBEDTLS_HEAP_SIZE=30000
CONFIG_MBEDTLS_SSL_MAX_CONTENT_LEN=2048
CONFIG_MBEDTLS_PEM_CERTIFICATE_FORMAT=n
CONFIG_MBEDTLS_SERVER_NAME_INDICATION=n

CONFIG_NET_TX_STACK_SIZE=2048
CONFIG_NET_RX_STACK_SIZE=2048

CONFIG_NET_PKT_RX_COUNT=10
CONFIG_NET_PKT_TX_COUNT=10

CONFIG_NET_BUF_RX_COUNT=20
CONFIG_NET_BUF_TX_COUNT=20

CONFIG_NET_MAX_CONTEXTS=10

# For IPv6
CONFIG_NET_BUF_DATA_SIZE=256            

CONFIG_NET_SHELL=y    
CONFIG_NET_L2_WIFI_SHELL=y                  

CONFIG_ENTROPY_GENERATOR=y              
CONFIG_TEST_RANDOM_GENERATOR=y          

CONFIG_NET_L2_ETHERNET=y

CONFIG_PRINTK_BUFFER_SIZE=2048

And this is the config.h file with the IP and ports:
#ifndef __CONFIG_H__
#define __CONFIG_H__

// #define SERVER_HOSTNAME      "broker.emqx.io" /*MQTT Hostname*/
// #define SERVER_ADDR      "35.172.255.228"            // broker.emqx.io
#define SERVER_HOSTNAME     "test.mosquitto.org"
#define SERVER_ADDR     "5.196.78.28"             // test.mosquitto.org
// #define SERVER_HOSTNAME      "localhost"
// #define SERVER_ADDR      ""            // localhost
// #define SERVER_HOSTNAME      "c666792db5ef42e5b9da3c1285f20daf"
// #define SERVER_ADDR      ""            // HiveMQ
#define SERVER_PORT             1883
#define SERVER_PORT_TLS         8883
#define MQTT_TOPIC      "testtopic/federzep"
#define MQTT_USER       /*NULL*/     "admin-user"
#define MQTT_PASS       /*NULL*/     "admin-password"

#define APP_CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MS  2000
#define APP_SLEEP_MSECS     500

#define APP_CONNECT_TRIES   3

#define APP_MQTT_BUFFER_SIZE    128

#define MQTT_CLIENTID       "zephyr_publisher"

#endif

This is the ca_certificate as it was given by zephyr (cert.h file) and which i haven't modified:
static const unsigned char ca_certificate[] = {"-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\r\n
MIIEAzCCAuugAwIBAgIUBY1hlCGvdj4NhBXkZ/uLUZNILAwwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEL\r\n
BQAwgZAxCzAJBgNVBAYTAkdCMRcwFQYDVQQIDA5Vbml0ZWQgS2luZ2RvbTEOMAwG\r\n
A1UEBwwFRGVyYnkxEjAQBgNVBAoMCU1vc3F1aXR0bzELMAkGA1UECwwCQ0ExFjAU\r\n
BgNVBAMMDW1vc3F1aXR0by5vcmcxHzAdBgkqhkiG9w0BCQEWEHJvZ2VyQGF0Y2hv\r\n
by5vcmcwHhcNMjAwNjA5MTEwNjM5WhcNMzAwNjA3MTEwNjM5WjCBkDELMAkGA1UE\r\n
BhMCR0IxFzAVBgNVBAgMDlVuaXRlZCBLaW5nZG9tMQ4wDAYDVQQHDAVEZXJieTES\r\n
MBAGA1UECgwJTW9zcXVpdHRvMQswCQYDVQQLDAJDQTEWMBQGA1UEAwwNbW9zcXVp\r\n
dHRvLm9yZzEfMB0GCSqGSIb3DQEJARYQcm9nZXJAYXRjaG9vLm9yZzCCASIwDQYJ\r\n
KoZIhvcNAQEBBQADggEPADCCAQoCggEBAME0HKmIzfTOwkKLT3THHe+ObdizamPg\r\n
UZmD64Tf3zJdNeYGYn4CEXbyP6fy3tWc8S2boW6dzrH8SdFf9uo320GJA9B7U1FW\r\n
Te3xda/Lm3JFfaHjkWw7jBwcauQZjpGINHapHRlpiCZsquAthOgxW9SgDgYlGzEA\r\n
s06pkEFiMw+qDfLo/sxFKB6vQlFekMeCymjLCbNwPJyqyhFmPWwio/PDMruBTzPH\r\n
3cioBnrJWKXc3OjXdLGFJOfj7pP0j/dr2LH72eSvv3PQQFl90CZPFhrCUcRHSSxo\r\n
E6yjGOdnz7f6PveLIB574kQORwt8ePn0yidrTC1ictikED3nHYhMUOUCAwEAAaNT\r\n
MFEwHQYDVR0OBBYEFPVV6xBUFPiGKDyo5V3+Hbh4N9YSMB8GA1UdIwQYMBaAFPVV\r\n
6xBUFPiGKDyo5V3+Hbh4N9YSMA8GA1UdEwEB/wQFMAMBAf8wDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEL\r\n
BQADggEBAGa9kS21N70ThM6/Hj9D7mbVxKLBjVWe2TPsGfbl3rEDfZ+OKRZ2j6AC\r\n
6r7jb4TZO3dzF2p6dgbrlU71Y/4K0TdzIjRj3cQ3KSm41JvUQ0hZ/c04iGDg/xWf\r\n
+pp58nfPAYwuerruPNWmlStWAXf0UTqRtg4hQDWBuUFDJTuWuuBvEXudz74eh/wK\r\n
sMwfu1HFvjy5Z0iMDU8PUDepjVolOCue9ashlS4EB5IECdSR2TItnAIiIwimx839\r\n
LdUdRudafMu5T5Xma182OC0/u/xRlEm+tvKGGmfFcN0piqVl8OrSPBgIlb+1IKJE\r\n
m/XriWr/Cq4h/JfB7NTsezVslgkBaoU=\r\n
-----END CERTIFICATE-----\r\n"};

It worked with TLS connection disable but when I add the TLS configuration the following error appears:
[00:00:26.326,000] <inf> net_mqtt_publisher_sample: tls_init: 0 <OK>
[00:00:26.326,000] <inf> net_mqtt_publisher_sample: attempting to connect: 
[00:00:26.401,000] <err> net_sock_tls: Failed to parse CA certificate, err: -0x2180
[00:00:26.402,000] <inf> net_mqtt_publisher_sample: mqtt_connect: -22 <ERROR>
[00:00:26.957,000] <err> net_sock_tls: Failed to parse CA certificate, err: -0x2180
[00:00:26.959,000] <inf> net_mqtt_publisher_sample: mqtt_connect: -22 <ERROR>
[00:00:27.520,000] <err> net_sock_tls: Failed to parse CA certificate, err: -0x2180
[00:00:27.521,000] <inf> net_mqtt_publisher_sample: mqtt_connect: -22 <ERROR>
[00:00:28.021,000] <inf> net_mqtt_publisher_sample: try_to_connect: -22 <ERROR>

I'm trying the access with the username and password.
I have tried to change the broker (test.mosquitto.org and a local HiveMQ broker) and the respective certificate.
I will add that on MQTTX it connects correctly to both so the brokers should not be the problem.

I don't use zephyr-rots, but for MQTT over WebSockets, encrypted, with authenticated on test.mosquitto.org is using port 8091,  where is this configured in your code? or what port that you are trying to access to?

I used port 8883 because it was between the valid port reported on test.mosquitto.org.
WebSockets should  not be used but there is an option to turn them on.
I have edit the post adding also the config.h file.

Not knowing anything about zephyr specifically, the error message Failed to parse CA certificate seems to clearly indicate that you have either supplied a badly formatted CA certificate for this server or maybe none at all?

I have added the certificate above

Port 8883 is for "MQTT, encrypted, unauthenticated". Please see the page on test.mosquitto.org, it is clearly list the ports for various network type.

the error remains the same also on Port 8091. I also tried to remove the password and use port 8883 just with the certificate and it still gives me problems so I think the problems it's either the certificate itself or the portion of code that handles it. It's my first time using both zephyr and mqtt brokers so i don't know too much of it.

There are nothing wrong with the cert. If you are not using username and password, the port to be used should be "8081 : MQTT over WebSockets, encrypted, unauthenticated" (please read the doc and try to understand it). If you want to use port 8883, don't use web socket, use simply tcp connection.

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
